# Laravel Eloquent - haversine formula and pagination

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, haversine

### Code Review

I have created a topic on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156878/laravel-pagination-with-haversine-formula-in-it) branch.

### Question

I'm using haversine formula to count distance from selected post-code to desired destination.

*App\Models\Business.php*

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $latitude, $longitude, $radius)
{
    $query->getQuery()->orders = [];
    return $query->select('*')
                 ->selectRaw("( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) )  * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) AS distance")
                 ->having('distance', '<=', $radius)
                 ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

Everything seems pretty ok, except when i use `paginate()` method instead of `get()`

I have been looking for solution, there are lots of topics describing this problem, but seems that people didn't come up with good solution for it.

Some solutions in my case caused incorrect values.
Maybe i did something wrong - not sure...

However i came up with this solution and i would like to hear any feedback if it's ok in terms of performance and memory usage.

```
function custom_paginator($builder, $per_page)
{
    $path = current_route();
    $current_page = \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    if ( ! isset($builder->getQuery()->columns[1])) $count = $builder->count();
    else
    {
        $query = clone $builder->getQuery();
        $query->columns = [ $query->columns[1] ];
        $query->orders = null;
        $count = array_get(\DB::select("select count(*) as count from ({$query->toSql()}) as haversine", $query->getBindings()), 0)->count;
    }

    return new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $builder->forPage($current_page, $per_page)->get(),
        $count, $per_page, null, compact('path')
    );
}
```

I haven't got any more ideas how to improve it, at least it works and i dont need to call something like

```
count = count($results = $builder->get());
$items = $results->forPage($curPage, $perPage);
```

feedback really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you really need to create a custom paginator?

If not try to use default.

The other thing I didn't like is the raw queries, you are using a laravel so take as much advantage as you can.

You will need to show your controller action for more feedback.

To be honest stackoverflow is not really the best place for this question,
code review stack exchange would me more appropriate because you code already works and you just want to improve it

Comment: You might be right, i never used 'code review stack exchange', thanks for letting me know. I do need to use custom pagination as `paginate()` method won't work with `having` keyword. There is dynamic `distance` variable inside of SQL and is not seen when using default paginator from Laravel. This is quite common error - im not alone with this one. `(SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause')`

Comment: ok I see, then this is valid reason for you to customize, as you have no choice, just refactor your code a little more, also you may not need the subquery to get a count